# Iterate over three lists simultaneously in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I would like to ask how to iterate over three lists simultaneously in R.  Actually the same function as purr::walk2 does for two lists, but for three or more lists. I suppose that function I should use is purr::pwalk but not sure.

So I have 3 lists (same length):

```
buffers_points_with_data <-
  list.files(
    path = "data/buffers_points_with_data",
    pattern = "*.csv$",
    full.names = TRUE,
    recursive = FALSE
  )

species_data_CZ_moved <-
  list.files(
    path = "data/species_data_CZ_moved",
    pattern = "*.txt$",
    full.names = TRUE,
    recursive = FALSE
  )

species_data_GBIF_moved <-
  list.files(
    path = "data/species_data_GBIF_moved",
    pattern = "*.txt$",
    full.names = TRUE,
    recursive = FALSE
  )
```

And want to run:
Read first chr from list buffers_points_with_data, then first chr from second list, first chr from third list, continue to the end of script and start with second chr for each and so on.

```
{ 
    clim <- read.csv("data/buffers_points_with_data/Acer negundo.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") #replace by 1st list
    occ.sp1 <- na.exclude(read.table("data/species_data_CZ_moved/Acer negundo.txt", h = TRUE)) #replace by 2nd list
    occ.sp2 <- na.exclude(read.table("data/species_data_GBIF_moved/Acer negundo.txt", h = TRUE)) #replace by 3rd list
#code continues
}
```

I am pretty new to R and programming so I do apologies if this question has been asked elsewhere or  the text is somewhat confusing.

Any help or suggestions would be great.
Thank You.

Comment: Use a nested walk or map, after placing them in a list i.e. `list(buffers_points_with_data , species_data_CZ_moved , species_data_GBIF_moved) %>% map(~ map(.x, read.csv, header = TRUE))`

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `pmap()`?

Comment: The use of `Map` and `purrr::pmap` is good for when each list has the same type of argument in it. For instance, if you had `files <- list.files(...)` and `headers <- list(T, F)`, then `Map(read.csv, files, headers)` makes sense. But I don't see it being relevant here: since you want to do different things with each element, while one could contrive of some way, the complexity is likely not worth the expense. Further, you don't have `list`s, you have string vectors, in R that's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map` that can iterate over 3 lists simultaneously.

```
data <- Map(function(x, y, z) {
   clim <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",") 
   occ.sp1 <- na.exclude(read.table(y, header = TRUE)) 
   occ.sp2 <- na.exclude(read.table(z, header = TRUE)) 
   #Do something
   #Do something
}, buffers_points_with_data, species_data_CZ_moved, species_data_GBIF_moved)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list(buffers_points_with_data , species_data_CZ_moved , species_data_GBIF_moved) %>% 
        map(~ map(.x, read.csv, header = TRUE))
```